# Windows Phone 8: strcmp not found

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

I started looking into bringing our application which runs on Windows to Windows Phone 8. This application has a native component written in C++.

After some looking around, I found out that I cannot use directly the code into a Windows Phone 8 app. So my plan now is to create a static lib with the legacy code, then a Windows Runtime Component that uses the static lib then the C# app which will, in turn, use the component.

So I've started with the static lib. I've brought the files into the solution and when I want to compile, I get the following error:

```
Error 1 error C3861: 'strcmp': identifier not found
```

Any idea how can I solve this?

(I should also mention that I've googled for this issue and I've found something related to including "stdafx.h", however, if I try to do that, the file is not found. I'm not using any precompiled headers of my own in the static lib).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you include the header for `strcmp`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I had to include `<string.h>`.